# concatenating list of tuples python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples as seen below :

```
l = [(1,'Nick'),(4,'George'),(4,'George'),(3,'Nick')]
```

what i would like to do is merge the tuples with the same Name and add the corresponding numbers.
Result here should be :

```
l_res = [(4,'Nick'),(8,'George')]
```

How could this be done using python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of set and list comprehensions like this:

```
>>> l = [(1,'Nick'),(4,'George'),(4,'George'),(3,'Nick')]
>>> unique = set(e[1] for e in l)
>>> [(sum([x[0] for x in l if x[1] == n]), n) for n in unique]
[(8, 'George'), (4, 'Nick')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way is by using a Counter dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter

l = [(1,'Nick'),(4,'George'),(4,'George'),(3,'Nick')]

sum_dict = Counter()
for el in l:
    sum_dict[el[1]] += el[0]

print(sum_dict) # Output: Counter({'George': 8, 'Nick': 4})
```

If you really want a list of tuples (which doesn't seem like the best datatype for this data), you can easily convert it with list comprehension over `dict.items()`

```
sum_list = [(v,k) for k,v in sum_dict.items()]

print(sum_list) # Output: [('Nick', 4), ('George', 8)]
```

Comment: `list(dict.items())` is in the wrong order `(name, num)` though

Comment: @LMD fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate set as suggested in a previous answer or with an intermediate dictionary like this:

```
l = [(1,'Nick'),(4,'George'),(4,'George'),(3,'Nick')]

d = dict()

for v, t in l:
    d[t] = d.get(t, 0) + v

result = [(v, k) for k, v in d.items()]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[(4, 'Nick'), (8, 'George')]
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to turn `l_res` into a dict by name, adding the numbers:

```py
dic = {}
for tup in l:
    num, name = tup
    if name in dic:
        dic[name] += num
    else:
        dic[name] = num
```

to turn it back into a list:

```py
l_res = [(dic[k], k) for k in dic]
```